# What is the physical formula relating the current to voltage for the photoelectric effect?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

The I-V characteristic for a transistor is well known. I would like to know if there is a formula connecting the current to the voltage in the photoelectric effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "the" current and "the" voltage? There are several possible experimental setups. But in General, the current is determined by the light intensity and the voltage by the color.

Answer (score 0):

Current and voltage are not "connected" in photoelectric effect. Current is provided by electrons kicked out of the metal by the correct frequency of light. Voltage is stopping potential, which is related to the KE of the electrons, not to the electron current caused by the correct frequency of the light.

Comment: The current voltage relation is investigated in      https://users.wfu.edu/~bonin/Intermediate_Lab_Phys_265/Pasco_Photoelectric_Effect_Student_Version.pdf